# Can a shared memory space send data (non-POD) to another shared memory?

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory

I am working on an open-source project built to support parallel
computation on workstation networks, **like tuple spaces**, **distributed shared memory**, **message passing** etc.

Instead of going too broad, let's assume we have some sort of pseudo-IPC communication that does **NOT** involve processing multiple types, but it should handle a huge amount of queries in a limited amount of time. My solution to this would be using two shared memory pools or at least two shared sections of memory pools.

I was thinking of `#pragma data_seg` or two memory mapped files, but that means all of the processes must use the name or the handle of the same file mapping object and I'm not sure if it's bad for me or not. Two instances of the same class can comprehend the data that is in the shared memory, but what if the instances are being modified during the transition to the second shared memory pool?

**Would the second shared memory space *comprehend* the processed information from the first one without slowing the freshly created 'ecosystem' of data?**

I hope I managed to rewrite the answer properly.

Comment: Boost has a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) for that. In general, you have to deal with pointers and references by not using pointers or references; a discussion of alternatives may be rather too broad for a simple answer.

Comment: I understand the words, but don't understand their meaning. Could you please give an example of what you're trying to achieve, with more details?

Comment: I was aware of the fact that plain old data should do well. I've also edited my question to point out specific situations.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't fully formed - POD types will be absolutely fine - however you bring up std::string which means you are looking at non-pod types with pointers and the like.

You have to be careful with pointers.  Boost takes an approach of smart pointers which work on the following premise:  the offets are safe relative to the start of the shared memory region and can be shared across processes.  But to get it to another memory pool, you'll need to properly copy it - by allocating an instance in the second shared memory and copy the instance to that.